# Indent code in the same way as = in ex mode in Vim

Tags: vim

How can I indent code in command mode in Vim in the same way as <kbd>=</kbd> in visual mode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the normal command <kbd>=</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> with a range:

```
{range}normal! ==
```

It will apply <kbd>=</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> to each line in the passed range. You can
also try things with the <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> command, to reuse
last selection; and take a look in the helpful [`'<`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#'%3C) and [`'>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#'%3E) marks.

Comment: To indent the following, say, 8 lines (including the current one) use `:,+7norm!==` or `:norm!8==`.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>=</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> will fix indentation on a single line
<kbd>=</kbd><kbd>%</kbd> will fix indentation to the matching brace (if the cursor is on a brace)
<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> will go to the top of the file <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> and then fix indentation to the bottom of the file <kbd>=</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>

summary - <kbd>=</kbd> is followed by an movement key and will fix indentation in the range specified by the motion.
[This sheet](http://www.viemu.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif) shows the movement key in green, as you can see there are many options

Comment: This has no relation to whatis being asked